Powershell Get-Printer Exclude Printers from txt file
I am trying to use powershell to get all printers except the ones I have in an exclusion list. Once it has the names, it will update the exclusion list and alert me to the new printers found. However I am unable to filter out the exclusion list, some help on the syntax would be appreciated, or another way to get the same result would be good..
$PrinterServers = Get-ADComputer -f * | Where Name -Like 'SC-PS-0*'

$ExcludeList = Get-Content .\myExcludedPrinters.txt
$ExcludeList = $ExcludeList -Join '|'

$PrinterReport = ForEach($ps in $PrinterServers){

    Get-Printer -ComputerName $ps.Name | Where {$_.Name -notlike '*Redirected*' -and $_.Name -notmatch $ExcludeList} | Select ComputerName, Name, PortName, Location, Comment, Shared
}

The $PrinterReport should return 1 printer newly installed on two printservers

your code looks alright, the only problem I see is if any of the lines of myExcludedPrinters.txt has regex characters. You should use [regex]::Escape for each line in that case. It's unclear what do get on $PrinterReport after running the code.

Don't use '-notmatch' instead use '-notin' without joining like this:
$ExcludeList = Get-Content .\myExcludedPrinters.txt

Get-ADComputer -f * | Where Name -Like 'SC-PS-0*' |
ForEach { Get-Printer -ComputerName $_.Name } |
Where {$_.Name -notlike '*Redirected*' -and $_.Name -notin $ExcludeList} |
Select ComputerName, Name, PortName, Location, Comment, Shared

